# Why is the macro like WEXITSTATUS(status) implemented in this way?

Tags: c, gnu

I'm new to C, sorry if my question is basic, below is the code that confuses me:

**wait.h**

```
# define WEXITSTATUS(status)    __WEXITSTATUS (status)
```

**waitstatus.h**

```
/* If WIFEXITED(STATUS), the low-order 8 bits of the status.  */
#define __WEXITSTATUS(status)   (((status) & 0xff00) >> 8)
```

My questions are:

Q1-the comment says `(status) & 0xff00) >> 8` retrieves  the low-order 8 bits of the status.  but it looks like it retrieves the middle 8 bits(or the second low-order 8 bits) of the status?

Q2-why there is an intermediate macro `__WEXITSTATUS (status)` that connects `WEXITSTATUS(status)` with `(((status) & 0xff00) >> 8)`, why can't we put everything inside the `wait.h` as:

```
# define WEXITSTATUS(status)   (((status) & 0xff00) >> 8)
```

Comment: The comment is erroneous — it is the high-order 8 bits of a 16-bit quantity, not the low-order 8 bits, as you correctly deduce.  The low order 8 bits hold the signal number that killed the child if it died from a signal, and the 'core dump' status (`WCOREDUMP` — not standardized by POSIX).

Comment: The indirection probably helps with porting to some obscure platform (that is POSIX compliant but not based on Unix) where the information for the exit status is not in the upper 8 bits of a 16-bit number.  VMS (originally from DEC) would be one possibility, for example; MVS from IBM might be another.

Answer (score 3):

1. More explanation is provided in the [waitpid man page](https://linux.die.net/man/2/waitpid) as quoted below. That is, the comment is not referring to the `status` passed into the macro but rather the `status` from the described places.

> returns the exit status of the child. This consists of the least significant 8 bits of the status argument that the child specified in a call to exit(3) or _exit(2) or as the argument for a return statement in main()

2. Likely reason is that it allows `__WEXITSTATUS` to be used in multiple places.

Comment: Interesting ambiguity in the comment — but you're correct that it is the low-order 8 bits of the value passed to `exit()` or `_exit()` or any other variant of those.